# How to use ROWID in H2 database

Tags: h2

I would like to be able to run the query

```
select rowid from tablename;
```

In H2 so some tests can run. I know it's on the roadmap but is there a way of faking it till they make it?

H2 has a `_ROWID_` pseudo column, is it possible to set up a global alias so that rowid uses that pseudo column.

Or

if I create a user alias

```
create alias rowid for "org.h2.value.ValueUuid.getNewRandom";
```

This will work

```
select rowid() from tablename;
```

but it there a way of the call working without the parentheses

The main database is Oracle, I'm using H2 for some integration tests

Comment: Oracle's rowid is the phyiscal location of a row in the database, not just some random number. Why do you need that in Oracle in the first place? And if you **really** need it there, then using a random number in H2 will not make any sense at all.

Comment: H2's `_rowid_` does make the most sense for my needs as it matches up the best. The random uuid was a possible way around that would work in the scope of the test as it's short lived

Comment: H2's `_rowid_` is something **completely** different then Oracle's `rowid`. Are you maybe looking for `row_number()` in Oracle and H2 instead?

Comment: Cheers, I thought they were similar. A row identifier. If it's the equivalent of rownum then it just won't work and I'll have give up on having a H2 test.

Comment: H2's `_rowid_` seems to be similar to Oracle's `rownum` but it is something completely different the Oracle's `rowID`. I personally think that integration tests using a different DBMS then the one used in production are worthless anyway

Comment: Yea once you get past the trivial cases things start to break down. It's nice and fast though, thanks for your help.